# One Click Publish - is it suitable for publishing to production environment

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, publish, production-environment

One Click Publish - is it suitable (eg safe to use) for publishing a small/medium web application to a production server?

If it is not, what is it good for?

Answer (score 0):

I've used click once publishing for a smart client application, so that users can download updates to the application on startup.  I don't think click once is the best option for a web application, because it's more for consuming application updates, rather than deployments.  Using web deploy (MS deploy tool) or even just even using copy/paste is more for publishing a production application.

Comment: Yes, this is my gut feeling as well.